# How to make a .psf font work in a Linux console?

Tags: linux, console, fonts

First of all, I am not asking how to convert fonts.  However, I had converted an otf font into a pcf one, however when I use
`setfont aoeu.psf` I get `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console` error.  I was wondering how I can make the font work in a tty.  I have tried to find an answer to this problem, but I was unable to find an answer.

Comment: First of all, font does not work in "tty". It may work in some kind of **terminal emulator** like xterm, console (vty), putty etc.

``setfont`` is used for console only, so you should run it in console only.  Where do you run it? Putty? xterm?

Comment: I run it in tty2 (Press Ctrl-Alt-F2)

Comment: This is console that emulates terminal. Check you have access to (type ``tty`` command) and do it as root (``sudo setfont aoeu.psf``)